# Keyboard pops up after i dismiss DialogFragment

Tags: android

In my fragment, I call up a DialogFragment and then I call

```
getDialog().dismiss();
```

and have this in my onDismiss()

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
{

    InputMethodManager imm =
            (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive())
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

but for some reason after that, a keyboard seems to pop up when I go back to the fragment I've tried all sorts including trying to hide the keyboard in the callback on the fragment but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my fragment, I call up a `DialogFragment` and then I call

**Try this:**

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

**In your code**

```
@Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        hideKeyboard(getActivity());
    }
```

**Use `stateAlwaysHidden` in Menifest file**

```
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".chat.activity.ChatActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">

    </activity>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks i had that method already and i was trying it in the call back, i tried it in the onDismiss() as you suggested in your edit but same result

Comment: @BoluOkunaiya then use stateAlwaysHidden in menifest file

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `toggleSoftInput(int showFlags, int hideFlags)` which toggles state of soft keyboard. from doc

```
This method toggles the input method window display.
```

You can use `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` which forces Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the `InputMethodManager`, calling `hideSoftInputFromWindow`, passing in the token of the window containing your focused `view`.

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this block of code if you are in fragment

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWaYS_HIDDEN);
```

Or if you are in activity :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWaYS_HIDDEN);
```

Please make sure to do it before setting the content view , or before inflating the view